# Android JAVA how to check if some index of char array is empty

Tags: java, arrays

I m working with an array of characters in java. The array can have some missing entries in the middle and I need to know the leftmost index that is empty

My code for that is

```
private int checkMissingEntry(){
    int p = 0;  
    for(int i = characterArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if (characterArray[i] == ' '){
            p = i;
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

However, `characterArray[i] == ' '` does not detect empty character, the code always returns whatever p was originally assigned to, in this case 0. the if statement never gets executed.

I tried `'\0'` and `'\u0000'` but none seems to work.

What is the solution?

Comment: For me it works ok, new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ' ', 'e'}; it returns 4

Comment: ' ' isnt exactly empty, its just a space. Dont know if thats what you are looking for. Maybe you should check for null or characterArray[i] == 0. Check out this link http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why not search from left to right and return the index immediately when you've reached the first missing character?

**EDIT:** included example array with missing value

```
private int checkMissingEntry(){

     char[]characterArray = new char[4]; // 4 characters in 1 array
     characterArray[0] = 'a'; //but we'll only set values for 3 of them
     characterArray[2] = 'b'; //so: index 1 is your empty character
     characterArray[3] = 'd';


     for(int i = 0; i < characterArray.length ; i++){

         char c = characterArray[i]; //get the character at index i

         if(c =='\0' || c =='\u0000'){ //check for empty character
            return i; //return index
        }

    } return -1; //only returns -1 if characterArray does not contain the empty character
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int checkMissingEntry(){
    String tmp = new String(characterArray);
    if (tmp != null)
        return tmp.lastIndexOf(" ");
    return -1;
}
```